# php artisan migrate:install - php cli : could not find driver

Tags: php, laravel

i'm working on a Laravel website with Wamp, but actually i think this error : [cmd migrate install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLrJW.png) comes from my `php.ini` cli file.

My php.ini is here : D:\php-7.4.1-nts-Win32-vc15-x64

[php ini screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oKye.png)

As you can see, i have already uncomment pdo.
I think my problem come from `extension_dir="ext"`.
I tried to give him an absolute path : `extension_dir=D:/php-7.4.1-nts-Win32-vc15-x64/ext`
But still the same error. Just in case i've already uncomment my Wamp's php.ini file. What can i do? thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you have `PDO` and `pdo_mysql` entries available if you run `php -i`? Check that `Loaded Configuration File` corresponds to the `php.ini` file your changing too.

Comment: Wow man its ok problem solved, they are 2 php.ini files in my php folder, and i was only editing the php.ini-production, thinking that it was the php.ini. I edited the other and all works now thank you ! ;)